# Prove: Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, then suppose $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove: Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, then suppose $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. if there exists a point $c \in [a,b]$, such that $f(c) > 0. then $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx>0$.

This is what i have so far,
since $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(c)>0$ $\exists [t,s]$ such that $f(x) > f(x)/2$, $x \in [t,s]$ ...
and I have no idea how to continuous to prove that, anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to say that $f(x)>\dfrac{f(c)}{2}$ for $x$ in an interval $[t,s]$ containing $c$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales yes～

Comment: So then a rectangle with base the interval $[t,s]$ and height $\dfrac{f(c)}{2}$ would lie between the $x$-axis and the graph of $f$. Would that not imply that $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\ge (s-t)\cdot\dfrac{f(c)}{2}$?

Comment: Let $g(x) = \int_a^x f(x) dx$ Then $g'(x) \ge 0$ etc... Would that work?

Comment: I know it will $ \geq $ while I just need > and necessary not =

Answer (score 1):

First prove that $f(x)  \geqslant 0$ implies $\displaystyle \int_a^bf(x) \, dx \geqslant 0$.

This follows because for any partition $Q$ and lower Darboux sum $L(Q,f)$

$$0 \leqslant L(Q,f) \leqslant \sup_{P} L(P,f) = \int_a^bf(x) \, dx.$$

As you observed, if there is at least one point $c \in [a,b]$ where $f$ is continuous and $f(c) > 0$, then by continuity there exists a subinterval $[\alpha,\beta]$ with $c \in (\alpha, \beta)$ and where $f(x) > f(c)/2 > 0$ for all $x \in [\alpha,\beta]$. The infimum of $f$ on $[\alpha,\beta]$ must, therefore, be strictly greater than $0$.

Hence,

$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx \geqslant \int_\alpha^\beta f(x) \, dx\geqslant \inf_{x \in [\alpha,\beta]}f(x)(\beta - \alpha) > 0.$$

Here we are using $\displaystyle f(x) \geqslant g(x) \implies \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \geqslant \int_a^b g(x) \, dx$ which follows from the first part of the proof using $f(x) - g(x) \geqslant 0$ as the integrand. In particular,

$$f(x) \geqslant f(x) \chi_{[\alpha,\beta]} \implies \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \geqslant \int_\alpha^\beta f(x) \, dx, $$

and on $[\alpha,\beta]$,

$$f(x) \geqslant \inf_{x \in [\alpha,\beta]}f(x) \implies  \int_\alpha^\beta f(x) \, dx\geqslant \inf_{x \in [\alpha,\beta]}f(x)(\beta - \alpha) .$$

Comment: while I need to prove is > 0 rather than >&= 0 , it's still work?

Comment: Yes it does -- will modify above.

Comment: I see ....Thank you so much

Comment: @Helen: You're welcome.